# Running html documents in Windows 10 Home edition

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have used Windows 10 Home edition and Microsoft Edge.
In Inetpub, I have html documents. 
For example;
    [image]

I have tried to run my html documents in Edge, Chrome and Mozilla. They don’t work.
In Edge I get this eror message:
[image]

My inetpub structure is like this:
 [image]

Do you have an idea, what should I do?

Comment: If its just a strait up html file, can't you just open it in chrome directly?

Comment: Try using chrome, not edge. Also, your html is missing a `head`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; but still have the same problem when I use google or mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; but still have the same problem when I use google or mozilla. In google, I can not see message in console. In mozila, it says "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared"  .   I added                                                                     <head>   these lines to my html document as well                        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  .

Answer (score 0):

You can also try bringing the code itself up to jsBin putting it in the html section and watching the output.

https://jsbin.com/nexufobuto/edit?html,output